# Node.js postman, sending JSON response to the client/browser

Tags: node.js

I am trying to learn node.js and I am stuck trying to send the JSON to the browser, I have not tried to consume the REST service because apparently the JSON is not being sent, it does not appear in postman.

This is my code:

Database connections pool

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    database: "dbname",
    user: "root",
    password: "",
    debug: true
});

module.exports.pool = pool;
```

Index

```
const Joi = require('joi');
const connections = require('./connections')
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());


function getClients() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        connections.pool.getConnection((error, connection) => {
            connection.query("select * from clientes", (error, rows) => {        
                if(error) {         
                    reject(new Error);
                }
                else {
                    resolve(JSON.stringify(rows));
                }
            })
            connection.release();
        })
    });
} 


app.get('/', (req, res) => {  
    getClients().then((rows) => {console.log(rows)})
                .catch(err => err);
    console.log(res);

    res.end();
});


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`listening on port ${PORT}`));
```

In this part:

```
getClients().then((rows) => {console.log(rows)})
```

It logs the correct JSON response at the end however it calls a lot my attention that I am getting a very long server response before the JSON string.

when I use res.send(rows) it displays nothing, postman gives me 200 response and blank page.

I literally started learning NODEJS 3 days ago and I have been stuck with this for one day :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not sending any data in response. 
`res.send` does not send JSON it sends only string use `res.json()`

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {  
    getClients()
    .then((rows) => res.json(rows))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json(err));
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I also don't need this line anymore resolve(JSON.stringify(rows)); instead just resolve(rows); and with your code I got the JSON response on the browser!